# Implementation 3D tiles into cesium itself

Tags: gis, tiles, cesiumjs

I am trying to implement 3D tiles into the project based on cesium. I am using cesium as npm in one angular project. I am quite confused, how to implement 3D Tiles. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to frame your questions properly

Answer (score 0):

cesium has a [`3d-tiles` branch](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/3d-tiles) – I believe for now you have to use a custom build (instead of the npm version).

Comment: Can you give me the advice how can I provide a custom build of the 3d-tiles branch and use it as npm package please? I have tried to build it "npm-way" but it did not work...

Comment: assuming you know how to use git:
clone the [cesium repo](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium), then check out the `3d-tiles` branch
— [build the code](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/master/Documentation/Contributors/BuildGuide/README.md)
— to learn about how to `require()` cesium in your code, read https://cesiumjs.org/2016/01/26/Cesium-and-Webpack/

Comment: @MichaelKnave if that helped, please mark the question as answered.